# Get rates for each employee on every product

Tags: sql

I have three tables    a b c

a has

```
empId | empName
------+------------
  1   | kevin
  2   | john
  3   | kate
```

b has

```
prodId | prodName
-------+------------
   1   | apple
   2   | banana
   3   | cherry
```

c is empty and has columns

```
empId(fk) | prodID(fk) | rate
```

How to get following result?

```
empID | prodName | rate 
------+----------+------
   1  | apple    | 0.00
   1  | banana   | 0.00
   1  | cherry   | 0.00
   2  | apple    | 0.00
   2  | banana   | 0.00
   2  | cherry   | 0.00
   3  | apple    | 0.00
   3  | banana   | 0.00
   3  | cherry   | 0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  select a.empid,b.prodname,0.00 as rate
  from a as a cross join b as b
```